# Updating a related table with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three tables:

```
MonitoringGroup - 1:N - MonitoringGroupFacility - N:1 - Facility.
```

`MonitoringGroupFacility` is the association table that allows a many-to-many relationship between the other two. It has two attributes as a composite key (the primary keys from the related tables).

Create, retrieve and delete functionality is OK. When I try to update an existing relationship in the association table, nothing happens.  No exception is returned.

This code will make changes to the `MonitoringGroup` table, but not the `MonitoringGroupFacility` table.

Before calling `Update()`, the test function removes the desired `Facility` from `MonitoringGroup.Facilities` and adds a different one.  I've checked 'this' in the code below and it contains the correct information (Facility 1 is replaced with Facility 2).

```
using (var context = new MyConnection())
{
    try
    {
        context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        context.Entry(this).State = EntityState.Modified
        context.SaveChanges();

        return true;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        logger.Error(ex);
        return false;
     }
}
```

Using `.Attach()` throws an exception.

I have also tried to set `EntityState` specifically on the `Facilities` collection, which failed.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would edit your question and add in details about the models so we can better understand how you have them defined. That would also help us to understand what `this` looks like.

Comment: The question is unclear but the code shows a *lot* of problems. EF is an ORM and doesn't deal with tables, it deals with application objects. A DbContext isn't a connection, in fact no connection is made until you either read some objects or *persist all pending changes* with `SaveChanges`. It's a multi-entity *Unit-of-Work* that tracks the state of all entities it loads. There's almost never any reason to try and modify entity state. And that `context.Entry(this)` means you tried to make your *entity* save itself through the ... Unit-of-Work that's supposed to own it

Comment: If you use EF *correctly*, that means *outside* the entities, and the entities actually refer to each other with properties, eg if `MonitoringGroup` has a `List<MonitoringGroupFacility> Facilities` property, and `MonitoringGroupFacility` has `Facility`, you may not have to do *anything* if all the objects were loaded through the DbContext. A single call to SaveChanges will save all changed objects automatically. If the objects came eg as DTOs, you only need to call `Update(monitoringGroup)` to start tracking all reachable objects in the `Modified` state

Comment: What is the actual code that  `removes the desired Facility from MonitoringGroup.Facilities and adds a different one.`? Where does it load groups and facilities from? It needs to be rewritten to use EF correctly but the change could be minimal - just create the context properly and only call `SaveChanges` at the very end

Comment: @devlincarnate Unfortunately, this is not a personal project and I can't post details on the models.  However, MonitoringGroup contains a list of related Facilities.  I can easily insert a new MonitoringGroup and relate it to a Facility using Attach().  EF takes care of the association entity with no additional code.    I'm just trying to understand how to update an existing relationship in a similar manner.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I understand EF is an ORM, but that does not negate the fact I have a relational database system connected to my data access layer which is built on EF.  Everything EF is doing modifies the database at some point .. which is the ultimate goal in this case.

Comment: Some additional clarification ... the MonitoringGroupFacility entity (table) does not appear in the .EDMX.  EF understands there is a M:N relationship based on the database model (doing database first) but does not show this entity or create a class for it.  It only exists to link MonitoringGroup and Facility and I don't seem to have a way of directly accessing it.  Referential integrity takes care of deletes, and using context.MonitoringGroups.Attach() takes care of adding a new group and any relationships to Facilities.  Updating an existing relationship is proving elusive.

Comment: @JasonRS EDMX stopped being used once code-first came out. Which EF version are you using? EF 6? Something earlier? Is this a legacy project perhaps? What do your classes and code look like? Post the actual code, don't describe it. We can't guess why relations don't work without the code. The code you posted here is definitely *not* how EF is used and frankly, something I've never seen. ORMs are meant to decouple entities from the database, `context.Entry(this)` means the data access code is inside the entity